# Using a referenced C# object in a seperate class/form

Tags: c#

I've got a Windows Form program that creates a Config object which contains various configuration variables used by my program.
Within the main form, it contains a button to open a new configuration form, where it passes the Config object as a reference -

```
FormConfig button = new FormConfig(ref config);
            button.ShowDialog();
```

Now in the FormConfig class, I can access the Config object within the main constructor

```
public FormConfig(ref Config config)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            // can access config.xyz OK here
        }
```

However within the new form, I've got a button that calls another function that needs to access the reference Config object, however I'm struggling to find a clean way to do so.
I can create another Config object as part of the FormConfig class, and then copy the referenced Config to it in the main constructor, however then the original config object doesn't get updated.

How can I achieve this?

PS apologies in advance if this is already answered, but my searches have so far failed to find a solution, possibly because I'm not sure what the correct search terms should be.

Comment: Please provide where you need the config and how you update it.

Comment: Is `Config` a class? If so you don't need to pass it by `ref`. Does that help?

Comment: What you need the config for? Maybe it's better for you to have a config file that can access through the whole application.

Comment: Save provided config object to the private member in the FormConfig, so button handlers will have access to it.

Comment: @ikerbera - A `Config` class is a better abstraction than a file. It's usually good to avoid technology dependencies.

Comment: How you check that _the original config object doesn't get updated_?

Comment: At the moment the main program simply creates a Config object, and the basic Config constructor sets various variables to hardcoded default values.

Within the new form, I want to be able to load those variables in to the form (this works fine), be able to edit them, then have them updated in the original Config object.

Comment: @Enigmativity Config is a class, but I thought if I don't use ref, then the original Object gets copied?

Comment: @Fabio, the original config object does get updated, which is what I want it to do.

Comment: How about making Config a `static` class?

Comment: You should definitly have a look at how reference-types and ref works. A class-instance isn´t "copied", as you say. It´s **reference** is copied. However changing anything on that reference will be reflected in all references to the same **instance**, which is what you seem to want. So imit the `ref` and every variable referencing your config **is** updated.

Comment: As you said _the original object does get updated, which is what I want it to do_ - so what is the question? You already have desired behaviour.

Comment: @Fabio I do have access within the main FormConfig constructor, however any other function within the FormConfig class doesn't get access to the referenced Config Object. I can copy the object and access the properties, but then any changes are made to that copy of the object, and not the original object.

Comment: @cmos I never thought about that. I'll admit my knowledge on 'static' is very limited, so I'm off to do some reading, as I think that may achieve what I want.

Comment: @EmmCee, what you mean by copying? `Me.localConfig = givenConfig` will create copy of **reference**, but both `localConfig` and `givenConfig` will still reference to the same object(same place in the memory) and all updates to the properties will reflect both variables.

Comment: Just show the code where you config object consumed by main form and by config form.

Comment: @EmmCee - "any changes are made to that copy of the object, and not the original object" - Wrong. You are dealing with a reference type meaning that the reference is copied, not the object itself. All copies reference the same instance of the object. Why don't you just try it and see?

Answer (score -1):

And the solution thanks to @cmos, is to declare the Config class as static, which negates the need to use any referencing or passing objects between classes/functions -

```
public static class Config
{
     public static bool SettingA = true;
}
```

Which means I can access and modify the Config object from anywhere within the same namespace with the following code, without needing to have a class instance -

```
Config.SettingA
```

Thanks to all those who helped point me in the right direction.

Comment: Good example where quick workaround will lead to the wrong path. But it depends on the project requirements.

Comment: Its practical.  Do make sure that dialog only has an OK button and not a Close or Cancel button.

Comment: This is not a good long-term solution. This will make your code fragile to changes and make it harder to test. In general passing objects around is better that static variables.

Comment: I can see the potential pitfalls of this method, however it's only for some basic setting values. This area of code will get revisited again as I'm still figuring out exactly what I need and don't need. This program is talking to an embedded controller, and I'm still at the point of working out the intricacies of handling the data exchanges, so just need someway to change settings without having to edit the code.

Comment: @Enigmativity previously I've used Program.Form1.Method() to access methods in the parent class/form, however I feel that isn't an ideal way. Is there a better method? I still need to go and get a better understanding of references, but I'd be appreciative of any pointers to things I should be looking at.

Comment: @EmmCee - The method you are suggest requires you to edit the code when you change settings. It also requires you to compile all of your code every time your settings change. It's not overly practical.

Comment: @EmmCee - Ideally you want code like this: `config.Set<int>("life", 42)` & `int life = config.Get<int>("life")`. Then you can pull the values from a text file at run-time and not need to re-compile your code.

Comment: @Enigmativity ironically, I have used that method in the past. The other program I'm working on when I get time/can be motivated, I use a dictionary object for settings, however most of the settings there are strings with a few doubles, whereas this program 99% of settings are integers, so I thought I'd try a different approach.
I'm using Serialization to save/load my Config object, and it appears to be working.

Thanks for the input, as with most languages, there are more than one way to achieve things, and it's always good to see how others do things.

Comment: @EmmCee - The suggestion I've made (i.e. `int life = config.Get<int>("life")`) could use a dictionary under the hood, but it is strongly-type yet late-bound.